Please, Can anyone help me recover these Emerald Green Arborvitae?
I planted them last year in May.  Established and doing well through out the year.  But they started to turn brown this spring. Now I water them every day.  Still the same.  Please help!!!
Should I water them more or less?
Thanks



If you want advice on "water more or less" you need to [edit] to inform how much (not how often, which you say is now daily, but probably wasn't until the damage was done) you are watering now. A recent question the questioner was revealed to be watering daily for 15 seconds per plant, so barely any water (on 6 foot tall trees in that case.) What volume of water are you applying to the plants?

Thanks! Yes, you are right.  I started watering them daily after I saw brownish.  I water them about a gallon each tree daily.
